# Help out the solution for the following condition

Tags: c, sockets

My code is

```
if(s==-1)
{
    //conection is made 
}
else
{
    //already connected  
}
while(----)  
    //rest part continues
```

In this when I execute this program, for the first time if connection is not made, IF part gets executed and while condition gets executing normally. Then if I recompile this, then I want while part to be executed first not repeating the connections part. So what checks I have to insert inside the code so that for the second time compilation, straight away while part must be get executed?

Comment: Normally, when a program is finished, the connection is lost, piggy backing onto an existing connection is often difficult.  Please also note which language you are using to help others give you an accurate answer

Comment: You are in control of your code. At the beginning of the code, you must be creating the connection. You should and always should check after doing so that it was successful. If it was not, then dont run the code, maybe retry to connect, if it was do the code you want. Other than your "already connected" comment, the code doesnt seem out of place. But perhaps this is becaues we see only limited context

Comment: In this condition, server connection is remain unchanged, only client side program is getting executed.So what should do?

Comment: Either, the explaination of your problem is unclear, or your understanding is. You're writing a client app. What happens server end is irrelevant to your client app. Your client app needs to connect, check it connected, do its thing and close. The server is not changed by this.

Comment: Then this really isnt making any sense! If you have 3 machines, server, client1, client2. server code cant run on the 2 clients, similarly the client code wont be running on server. Im gonna back out of answering this as clearly I dont understand

Comment: What should do if we want client1 program to be executed again with same server connection without searching for a new connection?

Comment: As someone else explained you need something there to keep a connection active. If an application terminates, even if you dont think it closed the connection, after sometime (usually not long) the server will give up on the client, as for trying to find it to reuse it, it would be difficult. Only other way is to create a service application which your client connects to and the service holds the connection and then you have to pass information between the service and the client. So, Im not going to answer further.

Comment: How is compilation relevant in the above question? Compile you code any number of times, the output is still the same executable!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you would want to do it, but if I understand correctly you want to persist some state **outside** your running program between its different invocations.
You cannot use your in-program variables to maintain this state because each invocation will re-initialize them all over. You can use some file-system marker (temp files for ex), if you dont want to use database for such state maintenence.